# In MongoDB, can you have non-sparse compound indexes containing 2dsphere (version 2) fields?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have documents of the form

```
{
  _id: String,
  quality : String,
  loc: {
    type: String,
    coodinates: [Number]
  }
}
```

The MongoDB documentation says that `2dsphere` indexes are sparse by default, but is not clear about whether they can be forced to be non-sparse.

Can I define a compound index `{quality: 1, loc: '2dsphere'}` which is *not* sparse? That is, can I define a index where I can search for documents with a specific `quality`, even if the documents do not have a `loc`.

I can't find anything in the documentation of either MongoDB or Mongoose (the ORM that I am using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR unfortunately **NO** 
to check/reproduce it on Mongo Shell:

```
use temp
db.places.insert({loc: {type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.88, 40.78 ] }, name: "La Guardia Airport", category : "Airport" })
db.places.insert({loc: {type: "Point", coordinates: [-73.97, 40.77 ]}, name: "Central Park", category : "Parks"})
db.places.insert({name: "test no geo", category : "test"})
db.places.createIndex( { category:1, loc : "2dsphere"}, {sparse:false, name:'catsp'})
db.places.find({category:'Parks'}).hint('catsp')[0]
>>> { "_id" : ObjectId("5536d3e9d97d8ef614b8c1f6"), "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -73.97, 40.77 ] }, "name" : "Central Park", "category" : "Parks" }
db.places.find({category:'test'}).hint('catsp')
>>> you will get NOTHING
```

> > > 

Comment: I was going to place a ticket in jira requesting to improve the documentation  and remove the ambiguity on this, then I realized that it is mentioned in the docs albeit it the wrong place  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/ where it states loud and clear: "For sparse compound indexes that contain a geospatial key (i.e. 2dsphere, 2d, or geoHaystack index keys) along with ascending/descending index key(s), only the existence of the geospatial field(s) in a document determine whether the index references the document."